# I want to retreive all images in a wordpress post (all from the media gallery) and show them in a lighbox

Tags: wordpress

I have this code that retrieves all images for the active page:

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

I need some help to open the images in a lightbox with the post/page title and navigation such as this https://simplelightbox.com/ one.

I am just learning the code so I desperately need some help.

I tried using fancy lightbox plugin but that did not work as the lightbox did not launch. For now I am hiding and showing the images using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I've created the following shortcode:

```
function so_all_images_lightbox() {
    $output = '';
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        $output .= '<a class="lightboximage" href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id).'">';
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
        $output .= '</a>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('all_images_lightbox','so_all_images_lightbox');
```

Add [all_images_lightbox] to the site you want the gallery to be on. And it will display the images with a link to the image file.

Then you'll also need a lightbox-container somewhere in your documents (preferably short before the footer to avoid stacking problems):

```
function so_output_lightbox_container() { ?>
<div id="imagelightbox" class="image-lightbox">
  <a id="close-lightbox" title="Close Lightbox" class="close-lightbox"></a>
  <div id="imagecontainer"></div>
</div>
<?php }
add_action('get_footer', 'so_output_lightbox_container');
```

and the styling for it (you could also put this in the customizer css or your child theme css)

```
function so_output_lightbox_container_css() { ?>
<style>
    .image-lightbox {
        display: none;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.90);
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .image-lightbox.active {
        display: block;
        z-index: 99;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #imagecontainer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'so_output_lightbox_container_css');
```

Finally, you'd need some javascript to load the according images to the lightbox instead of follwing the link:

```
function so_output_lightbox_container_js() { ?>
<script>
    ( function() {
        lightboxInit = function () {
            const lightboximage = document.getElementsByClassName('lightboximage');
            const imagelightbox = document.getElementById('imagelightbox');
            const imagecontainer = document.getElementById('imagecontainer');
            const lightboxbclose = document.getElementById('close-lightbox');

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(lightboximage, function (el) {
                    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        let imgfile = this.getAttribute("href");
                        imagelightbox.classList.add("active");
                        imagecontainer.innerHTML = '<img alt="Click to close" src="' + imgfile + '">';
                    });
            });

            lightboxbclose.addEventListener('click', function () {
                imagelightbox.classList.remove("active");
                imagecontainer.style.height = '';
                imagecontainer.style.paddingBottom = '';
            });

            imagelightbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
                imagelightbox.classList.remove("active");
            });
        }
        lightboxInit();
    } )();
</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'so_output_lightbox_container_js');
```

Tested by quickly throwing all of it in my functions.php and adding the shortcode to a site: Works. Click anywhere to close the lightbox. The styling of the additional close-button, I'll leave to you ;-)

---

**Update/Edit**:
To run the function from a template, just call the function within the template instead of running the shortcode. Add this to the template where needed:

```
echo so_output_lightbox_container();
```

You can then remove the line

```
add_shortcode('all_images_lightbox','so_all_images_lightbox');
```

of the first code block then, or leave it in place in case you may need the shortcode as well later.

---

**Update 2:**
To use an icon as a link, try replacing the first block with:

```
function so_all_images_lightbox() {
    $output = '';
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        $output .= '<span class="imgbx"><a class="lightboximage" href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id).'">';
        $output .= '<i class="fas fa-camera"></i>';
        $output .= '</a>';
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail').'</span>';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('all_images_lightbox','so_all_images_lightbox');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick assistance. I setup everything in the child function.php but still no luck. I am wondering if its the way I am calling the shortcode....see below    <script type="text/javascript">
   function gaj_images() {
   
   <?php echo do_shortcode("[all_images_lightbox]"); ?>
   }
   
   
</script>
<div class="tour_pics fa fa-camera" onclick="gaj_images()">
</div>

Comment: The shortcode doesn't need any javascript. Just throw it into the page within the wordpress editor with the brackets: [all_images_lightbox]. Or if you use Gutenberg, add a shortcode block and put [all_images_lightbox] in there.

Comment: Sorry I am not doing it in the page but in a template.

Comment: I was able to get the output. I will have to figure hot to call if using the fa icon.Thanks for assisting.

Comment: Nice that you got it working and accepted my answer. I don't know how font-awesome comes into play here, but let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I am using an fa icon to trigger the light-box. Basically when the  fa camera icon is clicked the lightbox should open. That's the reason i was using the onclick to call the function.

Comment: Ah, I see. You only need to edit the first code block then. Add the icon in between the <a class="lightboximage"...> and move the image below. Probably wrap a div or span around it with a handy class name so you can style it better. That should be it.